# Changing column names using regular expressions

Tags: r

I have five columns named organoleptic.1., organoleptic.2., organoleptic.3. and so forth in a data frame called "df". I want to rename them to organoleptic1, organoleptic2, organoleptic3, etc. That is, I want to remove the two dots surrounding the number. I did it using the names function:

```
names(df)[names(df) == "organoleptic.1."] <- "organoleptic1"
names(df)[names(df) == "organoleptic.2."] <- "organoleptic2"
names(df)[names(df) == "organoleptic.3."] <- "organoleptic3"
names(df)[names(df) == "organoleptic.4."] <- "organoleptic4"
names(df)[names(df) == "organoleptic.5."] <- "organoleptic5"
```

However, I would like to do it just typing one line of code. Is it possible to do that using regular expressions or any other trick? Many thx!

Comment: You can fix the name before you come to this issue. How are these column names created in the first place?

Comment: If you have names such as `v1 <- c('organoleptic.1.', 'organ.leptic.2.'); gsub('\\.(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\.', '', v1, perl=TRUE)#
[1] "organoleptic1" "organ.leptic2"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can try by using `gsub` function. Edit: Fixed from `sub` to `gsub`

```
colnames(df) <- gsub('.', '', colnames(df), fixed=TRUE)
```